# JQuery PageWalkthrough

Tags: jquery

i am using libraries from the following url, https://github.com/jwarby/jquery-pagewalkthrough.

I have to set/get/delete cookies onClose of the tutorial, with this i have to take value to next screen and depending upon the autoload or tutorial closed from user, we need to  autoload or close the tutorial. this will continue for all the other screens.

your help is appreciated.

Js file looks like as below

```
var flagSet;
var s;
var t;
var act;
var closeValue;
var coo;

$(document).ready(
        function() {    


            $('#Pagewalkthrough').pagewalkthrough(
                    {


                        steps : [ {
                            wrapper : '#loginTableHighlight',
                            margin : '0',
                            popup : {
                                content : '#highlight-accessable',
                                type : 'tooltip',
                                position : 'left',
                                offsetHorizontal : 20,
                                offsetVertical : 0,
                                width : '380'
                            },
                            accessable : true,
                            autoScroll: false,                      

                            }


                        ],

                        name : 'LoginPagewalkthrough',
                        onLoad : function(){
                               act= $.pagewalkthrough('isActive', 'Pagewalkthrough');
                                alert("onLoad: ");

                            alert("Active:"+act);
                                    if(onCookieLoad == null){
                                        alert("FlagSet onLoad: "+flagSet);
                                         if( closeValue != ''){
                                     return false;
                                 }
                                 else{
                                     $.pagewalkthrough('show','Pagewalkthrough');
                                     //$.removeCookie("LoginPagewalkthrough");
                                     return true;
                                 }
                                }               

                                // act= $.pagewalkthrough('isPageWalkthroughActive');
                                  alert("Onload :" +closeValue);
                                return true;

                        },

                        onRestart:function() {
                            //alert("-- onRestart --");
                            return true;

                        },

                        onClose : function() {
                            alert("-- onClose --");

                            closeValue = $('#jspClose a span').click(function(){
                                $('.walkthrough-main-menu a#open-Pagewalkthrough').removeClass();                                   
                            });

                            if(closeValue != '')
                                {
                                    flagSet=true;

                                    alert(" Flag Set as true:" +flagSet);
                                    alert(" Cookie:" +coo);
                                    alert(" Cookieval:" +s);

                                    return true;
                                }

                                return false;

                        },

                        onCookieLoad : function() {
                            alert("-- onCookieLoad --");
                            // s = $.pagewalkthrough('show','#Pagewalkthrough');
                            //setting cookie & value as true/false and remove 


                            if(closeValue != ''){
                                $.setCookie('LoginPagewalkthrough', 'false',1);
                                //setCookie('LoginPagewalkthrough', true,1);
                                coo=$.getCookie('LoginPagewalkthrough');

                                return true;
                            }

                            else{
                                $.setCookie('LoginPagewalkthrough', false,1);
                                coo=$.getCookie('LoginPagewalkthrough');
                                //coo=$.removeCookie("LoginPagewalkthrough");

                                return false;
                            }



                        }

                    });

                    window.onload = function(){ 
                    alert("Test Jquery FlagSet value:" +flagSet); 
                    }


            /*******************************************************************
             * NAVIGATION
             */

            $('.walkthrough-main-menu a').each(

                    function() {
                        //alert("-- Navigation --");
                        $('.walkthrough-main-menu').find('a.active')
                                .removeClass('active');

                        $(this).live('click', function() {
                            $(this).addClass('active');
                            var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
                            if (id == 'parameters')
                                return;
                            $.pagewalkthrough('show', id[1]);
                        }

                        );
                    }

            );

            $('.prev-step').live('click', function(e) {
                $.pagewalkthrough('prev', e);
            });

            $('.next-step').live('click', function(e) {
                $.pagewalkthrough('next', e);
            });

            $('.restart-step').live('click', function(e) {
                $.pagewalkthrough('restart', e);
            });

            $('.close-step').live('click', function(e) {
                $.pagewalkthrough('close');
            });


        }

);
```

Comment: What is the question? What are you not able to do?

Comment: i want to set a flag such way that, when we close the tutorial it should disable in remaining screens, and when we enable the tutorial in one screen it must be enable in remaining screens when user visits